# Setting content of a "higher" element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a layout that uses an "offcanvas" content element that slides in when you perform certain actions in the main app. The problem is that this element is placed outside and above the main content area so that actions performed in the :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  let showOffCanvas = 'show';

  return (
    <div id="app" className={'app app-header-fixed app-sidebar-fixed'}>
      <div id="content" className="app-content">
        <div>This is the main div and most components are rendered here-- this is where the action happens to populate the offcanvas element</div>
        <div>{props.children}</div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`offcanvas offcanvas-bottom ${showOffCanvas}`}
        id="offcanvas"
        aria-modal="true"
        role="dialog"
      >
        {Offcanvas content goes in here-- JSX component would change depending on use}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried multiple ways to handle this-- one way was setting the content of the offcanvas div in a redux slice, but redux doesn't like storing `JSX.Element` objects in state because it can't be serialized.

I also was reading up on using `React.render` to populate the div, but that also seems to be frowned on since the `render` is usually only used once, and it would be immutable.

Is there a standard way to handle this? One other thing I was considering was setting a string value for the content in the redux store, then depending on what that value is, rendering a different component in the offcanvas div but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what I needed was the [react `createPortal` API](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal). That does exactly what I was trying to do with some really hacky workarounds.